# Simplify XML tree - get relationship between elements

Tags: java, xml

I have complex XML tree which I would like to "reparse". What I would like to is to get all the objects with given attribute (let's say "type") and get relationship between them. Thus means - which would like to recreate tree structure of only elements with type attribute. In addition (this is why I can't use e.g. XSLT) I have to put to newly created object (element with type) reference to Node (Element) from base XML tree.

I checked *compareDocumentPosition* method but it only bases on line position, not on tree relationship

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is interesting! If I understand the problem correctly, you want to convert

```
                  Root                                Root
                /      \                            /      \ 
               N       T2         --->             T1       T2
             /   \    /   \                                /
            N    T1  T3    N                              T3
```

If so, I guess you could do something like this:

1. Select, using XPath perhaps, all elements with certain attribute and convert it to a Set
2. Remove all leaf nodes that are not in the set
3. Walk the tree bootom-up, moving each leaf up until it's parent is either root or a selected node
4. Repeat from 2. until there are no unselected leaf nodes

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean in step 2 but overall idea looks fine. The only thing is question - will the XPath NodeSet result be fine ordered? My task is more complex - actually, I have to recreate the tree you show on the right side using my custom Objects which have references to nodes from the leftside. Recreating tree means, that my objects are tree items themselves (parentNode+childNodes). So if I would like to produce my custom object based on xml node I have to be sure, that it parent already exists.

Comment: But... everything would be simplier, if I had XPath query, which for given node (e.g. taken from set you mentioned) will tell me which node is his real parent (first parent with given attribute). Does this query exist?

Comment: Hmm, yes, that would be something like `ancestor::*[@type][1]`, i.e. the 'nearest' ancestor with a 'type' attribute

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you have any limitations, but it may be worth parsing the xml into a class or several classes, then re-writing the XML if your given type == foo

Comment: I handled with this with full tree parsing (childList; DFS), but it sucks with styling if it would be possible I would prefer some fine XPath expressions:)

Comment: you can parse for when attribute = "type"
[try this link](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-jdom-example/) not sure if it would help